# How to add CPU information in nuspec

Tags: .net, configuration, nuget, nuget-package, nuspec

Just like how we can specify different .NET platform version in a `nuspec`,
How can I instruct the build to be executed against different specified CPU levels/targets 
like AnyCPU, `x86` or `x64` ...

in a `nuspec` file?

Is this even possible?

Comment: GilliVilla, did you find out how to do this?